Library in same directory as executable is not loaded with setuid
I have a rather specific problem:
I have a pre-compiled executable for some Software I have to run on different machines. The setup has pretty specific requirements:

A non-privileged user is able to execute it
setuid is turned on with root owner, so a non-privileged user is able to run the executable with root permissions
There is a library next to it the software needs to run

So, after some research, I found out that library loading with setuid is out of security reasons a bit different. From my understanding:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not evaluated
$ORIGIN in runpath/rpath is not evaluated

Makes sense so far. Now, if I look with elf into the executable, I see that RUNPATH is set to

Library runpath: [$ORIGIN:.]

From my understanding: Shouldn't "." be evaluated for library search, even with setuid?
Here is the core of my problem:

On Rhel-7.6, this works without issues
On Rhel-7.5, I cannot get this to work, as it is always trying to load the lib from /lib64/ and ignores the library in the directory of the executable - as long as setuid is set.

Has anyone an idea why that is happening? Or even a solution for this? I'm not really into this topic, everything I now recapitulated is from a (pretty extensive) Google search...
